# Storing values in binary search tree with C++

Tags: c++, tree, binary-search-tree, nodes, search-tree

This code for a standard binary search tree does not contain any information, only the value of the nodes. Is there any way I can contain another value, for example, age, in the nodes? So that the node number will be **id** and the value it is carrying will be the **age**.Essentially every node would contain a key-value pair.
Thank you for your help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node
{
int key;
struct node *left, *right;
};

//to create a new BST node
struct node *newNode(int item)
{
struct node *temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp->key = item;
temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
return temp;
}

// to do inorder traversal of BST
void inorder(struct node *root)
{
if (root != NULL)
{
inorder(root->left);
printf("%d \n", root->key);
inorder(root->right);
}
}

//function to insert a new node with given key in BST
struct node* initialize(struct node* node, int key)
{
/* If the tree is empty, return a new node */
if (node == NULL) return newNode(key);

/* Otherwise, recur down the tree */
if (key < node->key)
node->left = initialize(node->left, key);
else if (key > node->key)
node->right = initialize(node->right, key);

/* return the  node pointer */
return node;
}
struct node* insert(node* root, int key)
{
    // Create a new Node containing
    // the new element
    node* newnode = newNode(key);

    // Pointer to start traversing from root and
    // traverses downward path to search
    // where the new node to be inserted
    node* x = root;

    // Pointer y maintains the trailing
    // pointer of x
    node* y = NULL;

    while (x != NULL) {
        y = x;
        if (key < x->key)
            x = x->left;
        else
            x = x->right;
    }

    // If the root is NULL i.e the tree is empty
    // The new node is the root node
    if (y == NULL) {
        y = newnode;
    }

    // If the new key is less then the leaf node key
    // Assign the new node to be its left child
    else if (key < y->key){
        y->left = newnode;
    }

    // else assign the new node its right child
    else{
        y->right = newnode;
    }
   
    // Returns the pointer where the
    // new node is inserted
    return y;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? You can have `age` in `node` just as you have `key` in there.

Comment: Why not add it as a member in `node`?

Comment: You are allocating memory with malloc and deallocating it with delete. This causes undefined behavior. You could use `malloc` and `free` or `new`/`new[]` and `delete`/`delete[]` or smart pointers and containers.

Comment: You should not use `malloc` in C++ (except in very rare cases that you will probably never encounter), and absolutely not combine it with `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the node like

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct node
{
    Key key;
    Value value;
    struct node *left, *right;
};
```

Pay attention to that instead of malloc you should use the operator new.

For example

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct node<Key, Value>  *newNode( const Key &key, const Value &value )
{
    return new node<Key, Value> { key, value, nullptr, nullptr };
}
```

That is if you are writing a C++ program then use C++ constructions.

The function `insert` can be defined the following way

```
template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct node
{
    Key key;
    Value value;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

template <typename Key, typename Value>
struct node<Key, Value>  * newNode( const Key &key, const Value &value )
{
    return new node<Key, Value> { key, value, nullptr, nullptr };
}


template <typename Key, typename Value>
void insert( node<Key, Value> * &head, const Key &key, const Value &value )
{
    node<Key, Value> **current = &head;

    while ( *current != nullptr )
    {
        if ( key < ( *current )->key ) current = &( *current )->left;
        else current = &( *current )->right;
    }

    *current = newNode( key, value );
}
```

In main you can write

```
int main()
{
    node<int, unsigned int> *head = nullptr;

    //…
}
```

Comment: should probably use std::unique_ptr for the nodes, but still, no need for the user to create it's own map type.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a university project, don't bother creating your own Binary Search Tree unless you really want to learn how to do that. As C++ provides you a Binary Search Tree in the form of std::map and std::set

```
std::map<int, std::string> myMap
```

defines a tree that uses integers as keys, and stores std::strings.